# Finding date of worker became assignee of the issue in jira

Tags: sql, database, jira

I need to create report. Can some one tell me if it possible to get date of worker became assignee of the task in jira? I mean on some stage of the task he was assignee. And then assignee changed.

Answer (score 0):

That data is reported in the "history" tab of the Activity section.

Comment: I understand, but I must create report for all employees for half a year. That will be difficult to search Activity of each task of each worker. Where I can find this information in jira db, to create sql query?